# Query to get search result from google ... iOS

Tags: ios, search

i am developing an app in iOS to search any word in google search engine ,,,,

currently i am using this url to retrive the results which will be returned in JSON form

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?num=100&v=1.0&q=
```

where q is the key word to search about it ,,,

the problem is every time i am trying to search it just return 4 results ,,, how i can increase the results to more than 4 ,,,

and another thing ,, how to access the result pages like 1 2 3 ... in the url (i think its a parameter in the same url).

thanks ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The arguments you're looking for are:

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&gl=de&q=test&rsz=8&start=5
                                                                        /         /
                                                         result set size (1-8)   /
                                                                                /
                                                                         page offset
```

For more, see the [corresponding documentation](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/websearch/docs/reference.html#_fonje_args).

Also, keep in mind that this API is [deprecated](http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2010/11/introducing-google-apis-console-and-our.html)!